# Nginx: Unresolved host name (HTTPS)

Tags: nginx, https, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a minimal nginx configuration for an API, but I cant get SSL/HTTPS to work.

***Long story short: the `/healthcheck` endpoint works as intended, but not anything else.***

---

I have an API application running in a Docker container on a GCE instance alongside nginx.

```
           Internet
               +
               |
               |
               v
+--------------+----------------+
|             GCP               |
|                               |
|    +--------------------+     |
|    |Google Load Balancer|     |
|    +---------+----------+     |
|              |                |
|              |                |
|              |                |
|              v                |
|   +----------+------------+   |
|   | Google Compute Engine |   |
|   |                       |   |
|   | +-------------------+ |   |
|   | |  Server instance  | |   |
|   | |                   | |   |
|   | | +------+  +-----+ | |   |
|   | | |Docker|  |nginx| | |   |
|   | | |      |  +-----+ | |   |
|   | | | API  |          | |   |
|   | | +------+          | |   |
|   | +-------------------+ |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|  ---------------------------  |
+-------------------------------+
```

All HTTP traffic passes through the load balancer and hits nginx. If the endpoint is `/healthcheck` it goes directly to the API (which returns `200 OK`), while everything else should be routed back through the load balancer as HTTPS.

All HTTPS traffic should go straight to the API.

I have two `server` blocks in my config.
First block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  my-domain.com;

    location /healthcheck {
        proxy_pass http://API_IP:8080/healthcheck;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Second block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://API_IP:8080$request_uri;
    }
}
```

With the [Insomnia REST Client](https://insomnia.rest/):
When I hit `/healthcheck` either as HTTP or HTTPS it works, but `/users` or `/reviews` only gives the error message `Error: Couldn't resolve host name`. No status code, only this error message.

---

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**

Output from `wget -S my-domain.com/users`
*(Actual domain and IP is changed)*

```
$ wget -S my-domain.com/users
--2018-08-30 14:09:08--  http://my-domain.com/users
Resolving my-domain.com (my-domain.com)... *IP REDACTED*
Connecting to my-domain.com (my-domain.com)|*IP REDACTED*|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 12:09:09 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 194
  Location: https://my-domain.com/users
  Via: 1.1 google
Location: https://my-domain.com/users [following]
--2018-08-30 14:09:09--  https://my-domain.com/users
Resolving my-domain.com (my-domain.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘dev.api.godlypatruljen.no’
```

Comment: Try the request with `wget -S`. My guess is that the redirect returns an invalid string.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - Updated question now with the output.

Comment: Well, it's impossible to say with the redacted output, but try retyping `my-domain.com` in the nginx config file. Don't copy and paste. I've seen invisible utf8-characters in the weirdest places.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - Well, _something_ happened at least. It's not working, but now it's just stuck in a redirection-loop; Insomnia hangs forever, while `wget -S` stops itself after 20 redirections.

Oh, and the redacted IPs from the update are the same - they match the IP of the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Right.

I got a tips from a colleague which got me on the right track. It may not be the prettiest solution, but it works.

I replaced both the old `server` blocks with *one* new:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-domain.com;

    set $redirect_to_https 0;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        set $redirect_to_https 1;
    }

    if ($request_uri = '/healthcheck') {
        set $redirect_to_https 0;
    }

    if ($redirect_to_https = 1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$api_ip:$api_port;
    }
}
```

I have a few extra `location`s and `if`s as well (in addition to what's shown here) because of some edge-cases that I need to handle (static locations on the server, but not inside the container, etc), but this example should illustrate the solution quite well.